# Firefox window cut on the left side Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: firefox, 22.04

I wonder if it is because of wayland but this started to happen more often:
[image: firefox window left side is cut in Ubuntu 22.04 maximized]

If I minimize this window, this happens:

[image: minimized]

In the minimized view, I can't control the edge of the window. This happens to some of the multiple Firefox windows, which are open at the same time. I have an external monitor.
I wonder, if this is a known issue. If not, I will submit a bug report.

Comment: If it is a known issue, you should subscribe to the bug report. Subscribers help developers understand how widespread a problem is, help troubleshoot the problem, and help test fixes. More help = faster fixes.

Comment: @Genom Did you figure out a fix? Happens for me too. Only in Firefox. Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: @SwarangaSarma not really. I close the window and reopen again.